# SQL Server: select from table with/without aggregate columns using groupby

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregation, string-aggregation

I have the columns and rows for the table A,

| tableid | featureid | col3 | col4 | coldatetime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | AD | 4 | 2022-06-22 09:00:00 |
| 2 | 2 | BC | 5 | 2022-06-22 09:00:00 |
| 3 | 1 | AE | 6 | 2022-06-22 10:00:00 |
| 4 | 3 | BD | 7 | 2022-06-22 11:00:00 |
| 5 | 2 | BB | 8 | 2022-06-22 16:00:00 |

I need the following result in the SQL Server,

| featureid | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AD | 4,6 |
| 2 | BC | 5,8 |
| 3 | BD | 7 |

If I run the following query:

```
select featureid,
       STRING_AGG(col3,',') as col3,
       STRING_AGG(col4,',') as col4 
from table_server 
group by feature_id;
```

I am getting the following result,

| featureid | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AD,AE | 4,6 |
| 2 | BC,BD | 5,8 |
| 3 | BD | 7 |

How Should I change my query to get the Col3 to have only one record?

I have this clarification, whether this is possible or not?

I have zero knowledge with SQL Server, can anyone help me?

Comment: So why do you use STRING_AGG for col3 knowing that you only want a single value? Maybe just change that to MIN for col3?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need `MIN` instead of `STRING_AGG`

```sql
select
  s.featureid,
  MIN(s.col3, ',') as col3,
  STRING_AGG(s.col4, ',') as col4 
from table_server s
group by
  s.feature_id;
```